# Use Fiber microscope to view micron sized particles

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

Can I use Fiber microscope to see micron sized particles?
That's mean, can Fiber microscope be used as a typical optical microscope?
[Generic Handheld 400x Fiber Optical Microscope Inspection](https://goo.gl/JWhMqe)

[image: Fiber microscope]

Comment: What will a 400X zoom give you compared to the detail you can see by eye? Have you attempted to work it out?

Comment: check out this question and then see if the instrument will make the object you want to see large enough : https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26189/whats-the-smallest-size-a-human-eye-can-see